# Why do HTTP requests to `Host: localhost` not appear in Apache2 access logs?

Tags: apache2, lamp

I have the LAMP stack installed on my local machine to allow me to make WordPress without having to pay to host them during said making. I created an Apache2 custom log file using a bespoke log format, so that I could check the value of the `Host:` header in the requests that my browser was sending to the server (this was a troubleshooting measure to try and determine why a  configuration was not matching, which I since found was a WordPress issue). What I did find however was that requests made to `localhost` do not appear in the access log, while requests made to `my_virtual_host_server_name` do.

Both of the hostnames point to `127.0.0.1` in my `/etc/hosts` file, however `my_virtual_host_server_name` matches my `<VirtualHost>` configuration; however the `CustomLog` directive is defined within the main Apache configuration file, so it should apply to any request to the server. I don't really know where to start with this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have other_vhosts_access.log? If the request does not match the normal vhosts it is the fallback. With edited hosts file the name requests go to the localhost but have different headers.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, when my browser made a request to `my_virtual_host_server_name` it was matching a `<VirtualHost>` configuration which didn't specify any `CustomLog` directive, so it happily defaulted to the global `CustomLog` defenition as I intended. When the browser made a request to `localhost` however, this matched the default `<VirtualHost>` configuration `000-default.conf` which does contain a `CustomLog` defenition which was overriding the global configuration and consequently not logging information into the custom log file I defined within `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`; that is all.